# drupal 7 AT theme/Corolla/Footheme change logo link

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-themes

I'm using the Adaptive Theme and the Corolla and Foo subthemes. I need my logo link which usually goes to the home page of the site to go to another url altogether. I've looked in the templates (template.php and page.tpl.php) in the Corolla and Adaptive theme directories and all I can find is this code:

```
<?php if ($site_logo): ?>
            <div id="logo">
              <?php print $site_logo; ?>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
```

But I expected to find something with `<front>` in it. I tried wrapping:

```
<?php print $site_logo; ?> with a link, but to no avail.
```

I also tried taking out `$site_logo` after the word "print" but also to no avail. So what can I do to accomplish this?

J

Answer (score 1):

The codes you are looking are in `function adaptivetheme_preprocess_page(&$vars)` line 119 of ../themes/adapthivetheme/**at_core/inc/preprocess.inc** file.

So you should override the $site_logo variable in your theme template.php similar function.

Comment: I changed the file you mentioned (as shown below).This seems to work fine. But i'm guessing that I shouldn't be editing the include file, but just the template.php then. the code you've referenced (with my change in it) is:

     // Set up logo element
...
      $vars['site_logo'] = $vars['logo_img'] ? l($vars['logo_img'], 'http://mydomain.com', array('attributes' => array('title' => t('Home page')), 'html' => TRUE)) : '';
    }
So do I just copy the above code into template.php then?

Thanks much.
J

Comment: Yes, you are right. You should never edit the base theme. So, copy the function to your theme template.php and change it like this `MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars)`... If the answer solved your problem you can select it as acceptable and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

A little more detail building on the answer from TheodorosPloumis.  I ended up with a function like this in my template.php.  Note that you need to change "MYTHEME_" in the call to drupal_static as well as the main function name.

```
<?php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Set up logo element
  if (at_get_setting('toggle_logo', $theme_name) === 1) {
    $vars['site_logo'] = &drupal_static('MYTHEME__preprocess_page_site_logo');
    if (empty($vars['site_logo'])) {
      $logo_image_alt = check_plain(variable_get('site_name', t('Home page')));
      $logo_link = variable_get('logo_link', '<front>');
      if (at_get_setting('logo_title') == 1) {
        $vars['site_logo'] = $vars['logo_img'] ? l($vars['logo_img'], $logo_link, array('attributes' => array('title' => $logo_image_alt), 'html' => TRUE)) : '';
      }
      else {
        $vars['site_logo'] = $vars['logo_img'] ? l($vars['logo_img'], $logo_link, array('html' => TRUE)) : '';
      }
    }
    // Maintain backwards compatibility with 7.x-2.x sub-themes
    $vars['linked_site_logo'] = $vars['site_logo'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try that. Nice that you've added backward compatibility feature.
J